Creating Custom Option in LLVM
I want to create a custom option that reads a file. I've added the definition of this option in Options.td, and I am able to access the argument passed to this newly defined option in driver.cpp. Now, I want to access this argument in PassManager.cpp file. I'm completely in the dark about how to do this. Could anyone give me a lead on this?
I have added following snippet in options.td
 def readingfile : Joined<["-", "--"], "readingfile=">, Visibility<[ClangOption, CC1Option]>, HelpText<"whatever">;
And in driver.cpp iam able to print arg passed,
`if (Arg *A = C.getArgs().getLastArg(options::OPT_readingfile)) {
StringRef ProgName = A->getValue();
// Null program name cannot have a path.
if (!ProgName.empty()) {
    llvm::outs()<<ProgName.str();
}
llvm::outs() << "\n";

}`
I want to access this in PassManager.cpp for further processing.
